# Why is a naive `iter_swap`potentially much slower than `swap`?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, metaprogramming, swap

From David Abrahams and Aleksey Gurtovoy's book "C++ Template Metaprogramming", I learned that `iter_swap` (see below) would be much slower than `std::swap` sometimes. Although the book has some explanation, I did not quite get it, could someone explains the reason behind it with more details.

```
template <typename ForwardIt1>
void iter_swap(ForwardIt1 it1, ForwardIt1 it2){
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt1>::value_type T;
  T tmp = *it1;
  *it1 = *it2;
  *it2 = tmp;
}

template <typename ForwardIt1>
void swap_wrapper(ForwardIt1 it1, ForwardIt1 it2){
  std::swap(*it1, *it2);
}
```

By applying them on `std::list<std::vector<std::string>>::iterator`, I found the first is 10X slower than the second even when the size of the vector (whose elements are all small strings, length less than 10) is just 10.

Comment: Those are both *valid* `iter_swap`s. Neither are `swap`s. And there already exists `std::iter_swap`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you don't understand about the book's explanation (on page 19): "copying a vector means copying all of its elements, and each string element copied or assigned is likely to require a dynamic memory allocation and a bitwise copy of the string’s characters" whereas `std:swap()` "provides an efficient version of swap for vectors that just exchanges a few internal pointers"?

Comment: Actually, I can understand the explanation "literally". I cannot understand why cannot we just use the optimization technique used for `std::swap` for `iter_swap` to make `iter_swap` as efficient as `std::swap`. However, after you (@MichaelBurr) edited my question, I just realized that my question is stupid because `iter_swap` can be implemented as efficient as `std::swap`, i.e., `std::iter_swap`. Thanks @MichaelBurr !

Comment: All I did was correct  Aleksey Gurtovoy's name!  The key thing to realize is that `std::swap()` is efficient for `std::vector` because `std::vector` provides a specialization for `swap()` that knows about and takes advantage of the internals of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 6):

Your `iter_swap()` is often sub-optimal, if it "works" at all, and is not flat-out wrong.

1. There is a reason [`std::iter_swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) delegates to `swap()` using [argument-dependent-lookup](/questions/tagged/argument-dependent-lookup):
   Picking up tailored implementations.
2. In addition, the fallback `std::swap()` takes advantage of move-semantics when swapping, potentially eliminating costly resource-acquisition, which you didn't use.

Of course, both are irrelevant for trivial types.

Comment: You’re right but the question was *why* it’s suboptimal (you hint at that with move semantics but it’s probably not obvious how this impacts OP’s code).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Clarified it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've tried to add `std::move` (but I am not sure whether it will force move-semantics) on the RHSs of the three "assignment" in `iter_swap`. After "optimization", the first is still 5X slower than the second. I guess that some more advanced optimization techniques are used in `std::swap`.

Comment: @LongGong 1. Did you ask your compiler to optimize? 2. While the fallback `std::swap()` uses move-semantics, ADL leads to using the custom implementation, which is better.

Comment: @Deduplicator I used the default optimization level (i.e., `O0` for gcc). I have tried other optimization levels, I found that with `Ox` (x>0), for the version with `std::move`, the gap between the first and the second can be reduced to 2X, i.e., the  first is still 2X slower. For the one without `std::move`, after turning on optimization, the gap gets even larger (up to 100X).

Answer (score 2):

`std::swap` of a vector is a constant complexity operation.

The complexity of copying a vector increases linearly in relation to the length of the vector.

`T tmp = *it1` calls the copy constructor. `*it1 = *it2` and `*it2 = tmp` call the copy assignment operator.